# npm error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, command-line, terminal, npm

**I have an app that uses the Rails framework and implements AngularJs as part of the front end.**

**I have pushed everything to Heroku and have the Heroku Toolbelt installed, but when I try to migrate the db using "heroku run rake db:migrate" I receive the following error(s):**

```
Installing core plugins heroku-cli-addons, heroku-apps, heroku-fork, heroku-git, heroku-local, heroku-run, heroku-status...
Error installing package. Try running again with GODE_DEBUG=info to see more output.
 !    `run` is not a heroku command.
 !    Perhaps you meant `-h`, `2fa`, `auth`, `join`, `open`, `orgs`, `pg`, `ps` or `rake`.
 !    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.
```

> I then run the command "GODE_DEBUG=info heroku run rake db:migrate" and receive this error:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/Christopher_Pelnar/.heroku/node-v4.2.1-darwin-x64/bin/node" "/Users/Christopher_Pelnar/.heroku/node-v4.2.1-darwin-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/cli.js" "install" "heroku-cli-addons" "heroku-apps" "heroku-fork" "heroku-git" "heroku-local" "heroku-run" "heroku-status" "--loglevel=info"
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.8
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ETIMEDOUT 198.105.254.228:8080
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Christopher_Pelnar/.heroku/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Removing the proxy settings resolved the issue:**

`npm config rm proxy`
`npm config rm https-proxy`

Answer (score 0):

`npm config set registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
 npm config set strict-ssl false`

It's worked for me!