# Compilation fails on TACO 8.1 (Failed to fetch platform android)

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I upgraded to TACO 8.1 today, cleared Cordova cache in Tools > Options, cloned my git project, and now I'm getting this error when compiling for Android:

```
1>  Executing "before_platform_add"  hook for all plugins.
1>  No version supplied. Retrieving version from config.xml...
1>  Failed to fetch platform android
1>  Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
1>  Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
1>MDAVSCLI : error : tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED
```

Any idea?

- EDIT: I'm not behind a proxy
- EDIT: Same result when compiling for iOS
- EDIT: I tried repairing Visual Studio: no luck (same error)
- EDIT: I'm on Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio is being run as an administrator
- EDIT: I'm getting an error when building the "Ionic Tabs App" project that comes with Visual Studio: [image: List item]

Comment: Try clearing the Cordova cache by tools menu->options->Tools for Apache Cordova->Cordova Tools->Clear Cordova Cache.

Comment: @ElvisXia already did unfortunately (see my first sentence). I'm actually tempted to think that the problem started occurring from this point.

Comment: Try create a blank new project to see what happened? But the error seems more related to npm.

Comment: @AlanYao-MSFT yes it was! See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, I just solved it. Bear with me. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162560/error-tunneling-socket-could-not-be-established-cause-connect-econnrefused-10) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322739/npm-error-tunneling-socket-could-not-be-established-cause-connect-etimedout) put me on the right track.

I opened a command line and typed the following commands in order to check the configuration of the `npm` command used by Visual Studio:

```
cd C:\Users\Guillaume\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\vs-npm
npm config list
```

Here's what I got:

[image: npm config list]

As you can see, a proxy URL was specified (http://127.0.0.1:8888/). 
So I removed it using this command and it solved the problem:

```
npm config rm proxy
```

My guess is that Fiddler must have been running when `npm` was first installed or configured by Visual Studio...

Note to Microsoft: it would be good to use the current proxy config instead when building. And also, that setting should be reset when clearing Cordova's cache from Visual Studio...

Comment: You can also turn the auto proxy feature in VS TACO off by going to tools -> options -> Apache Cordova Tools and unchecking the "Automatically detect proxy configuration" checkbox. (Disclosure: I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova in Visual Studio)