# I can't install gulp-sass module in my gulp project

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp-sass

I do it one month ago, but now I come across with next problem. I tried to reinstall nodeJs. I installed gulp-scss extension, but it didn't install to. And now all extensions installing longer than usually. 1 package installing during for 20 minutes, internet connection is good..

```
   C:\WDM\blablabla.com>npm install gulp-sass --save
npm WARN package.json gulp-project@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json gulp-project@1.0.0 No README data
npm WARN package.json gulp-project@1.0.0 No license field.
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.

> spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall C:\WDM\blablabla.com\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\cross-spawn\node_modules\spawn-sync
> node postinstall

\
> node-sass@3.4.2 install C:\WDM\blablabla.com\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.4.2/win32-x64-46_binding.node":

tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ETIMEDOUT 192.168.0.1:8080

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@3.4.2 postinstall C:\WDM\blablabla.com\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\WDM\blablabla.com\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --
libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\WDM\\blablabla.com\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.3.1
gyp info using node@4.4.3 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\WDM\blablabla.com\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:63:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\WDM\blablabla.com\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:72:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\WDM\blablabla.com\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:81:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\WDM\blablabla.com\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:44:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\WDM\blablabla.com\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:29:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 [Error: not found: python2]
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\WDM\blablabla.com\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:63:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\WDM\blablabla.com\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:72:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\WDM\blablabla.com\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:81:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\WDM\blablabla.com\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:44:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\WDM\blablabla.com\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:29:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp verb `which` failed  python [Error: not found: python]
gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\WDM\blablabla.com\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:401:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\WDM\blablabla.com\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:356:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\WDM\\blablabla.com\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "
--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\WDM\blablabla.com\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "gulp-sass" "--save"
npm ERR! node v4.4.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-sass@3.4.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.4.2 postinstall script 'node scripts/build.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-sass
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\WDM\blablabla.com\npm-debug.log
```

During installation of files, they are showing in the directory, but after error they are deleted automatically.

After npm update I recive this message

```
C:\WDM\blablabla.com>npm install gulp-sass --save
normalizeTree -> network  - |----------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
normalizeTree -> network  - |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------normali
zeTree -> network  \ |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------normalizeTree
fetchMetadata -> network  / |################################----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

during an hour.

Comment: Try updating npm to the latest version (v3.8) which has much better windows support. npm upgrade -g npm

Answer (score 1):

Here are multiple existing questions answering your question. One of the answer might solve your problem. It seems to be an issue with the proxy settings of npm/your local machine.

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162560/error-tunneling-socket-could-not-be-established-cause-connect-econnrefused-10) & 
[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322739/npm-error-tunneling-socket-could-not-be-established-cause-connect-etimedout) regarding this topic.

Comment: Unfortunetly it doesn't help to me.

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem. The problem was in proxy server. I don't know why it was installed in my config..

I found an answer here  [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934343/how-to-restore-reset-npm-configuration-to-default-values)